# Using SSSD with multiple LDAP servers/domains

Tags: ldap, authentication, sssd, centos8, rhel8

I need to authenticate users using two separate LDAP servers.  Have configured SSSD with two domains but only one seems to be working.  I ran the command `authconfig --enablemkhomedir --enablesssd --enablesssdauth --updateall` and updated sssd.conf as follows:

```
[sssd]
domains = domain1, domain2
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2

[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root

[pam]
offline_credentials_expiration = 0


[domain/domain1]

auth_provider = ldap
id_provider = ldap

ldap_uri = ldaps://domain1
ldap_tls_reqcert = allow


[domain/domain2]

auth_provider = ldap
id_provider = ldap

ldap_uri = ldaps://domain2
ldap_tls_reqcert = allow
```

The results are that a user from domain2 (user2) is recognized but a user from domain1 (user1) is not found:

```
# id user2
uid=10(user2) gid=10(admin) groups=10(admin)

# id user1
id: 'user1': no such user
```

Any ideas to get domain1 working?  That server/auth was working fine when we were back with nslcd.conf but of course couldn't use two servers with nslcd, only the first server defined would work.  I'm a n00b when it comes to this stuff and all the nscd, nslcd, nsswitch.conf, authconfig, etc gets pretty confusing.  I didn't notice any errors in the /var/log/messages or SSSD logs.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that we needed to specify some certificate and key information, i.e. `ldap_tls_cacert`, `ldap_tls_cert` and `ldap_tls_key`.  With those defined, `domain1` was now reachable.